# ngFor not showing data Ionic 4

Tags: angular, api, rest, ionic-framework, ionic4

I tried to loop my data in *ngFor but it's not showing data but in my console, it's showing. Below is my code that I tried.

**api.service.ts**

```
    getOrder(orderId): Observable<CustomerOrder> {
       return this.http
      .get<CustomerOrder>(this.apiUrl + 'OrderProduct/' + orderId)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

**orderdetails.component.ts**

```
orderData: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.orderId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.orderId;
   this.apiService.getOrder(this.orderId).subscribe(res => {
  Object.assign(this.orderData, res);
  console.log(res);
});
}
```

**orderdetails.page.html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let ord of orderData">
      <ion-card-title>
        <h4 class="ion-text-center" style="font-weight: bold">{{ord.Customer?.Name}}</h4>
        <h5 class="ion-text-center">{{ord.OrderNo}}</h5>
      </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-content>
       <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Items: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.OrderProducts?.Product}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Quantity: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.Quantity}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Item Price: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.ItemPrice}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
       </ion-card-content>
      <ion-button type="button" color="primary"
                  style="float: right; padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 3px;" 
        (click)="closeOrder()">
        Close
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button type="button" color="danger"
                  style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;padding-bottom: 3px;">
        Cancel
      </ion-button>

    </ion-card>
```

In console it's showing data below it is
[image: Console data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. In the ts file, I wrapped data like this.

```
 this.apiService.getOrder(this.orderId).subscribe(res => {
  this.orderData = [res];
   console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Ahhh I see now your order result is not an array. Your approach works, but its a bit of a hack :)  No reason to iterate over what you know to be a single result. Try going back to the old way and using *ngif="orderData" and initializing orderData to null. The you can just refer to orderData.OrderId and such.

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with Ionic and is all about change detection in Angular.

It is because you are not waiting for the data to return before rendering the page.

The simplest way for the current state of your code would be to wrap your ion-card element with an NgContainer like so.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="orderData.length>1">
add you card HTML here
</ng-container>
```

The change in data will trigger [a change detection which will cause the page to re-render.](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)

But since you are using observables...a better way to do this would be:

1. Add an async listener to your HTML which consumes the returned data:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="orderData$ | async as orderData">
<ion-card *ngFor="let ord of orderData">
      <ion-card-title>
        <h4 class="ion-text-center" style="font-weight: bold">{{ord.Customer?.Name}}</h4>
        <h5 class="ion-text-center">{{ord.OrderNo}}</h5>
      </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-content>
       <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Items: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.OrderProducts?.Product}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Quantity: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.Quantity}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Item Price: </p>&nbsp;
            <ion-label>{{ord.ItemPrice}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
       </ion-card-content>
      <ion-button type="button" color="primary"
                  style="float: right; padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 3px;" 
        (click)="closeOrder()">
        Close
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button type="button" color="danger"
                  style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;padding-bottom: 3px;">
        Cancel
      </ion-button>
</ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

1. And then in your typescript file:

```
orderData$: Observable<Record<string, unknown>[]>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.orderId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.orderId;
   this.orderData$ = this.apiService.getOrder(this.orderId);
}
```